# Creating Users/Groups in Websphere

Tags: websphere-8, wsadmin

I am new to Websphere Application Server. I have created a dmgr and federated profiles into it. As part of my project, I need to create a set of users and map them against groups in Users and Groups section.

Now my question is, do we have any way to automate creating & mapping users/groups and avoid manual work for other environments.

Answer (score 1):

You could create users and groups via wsadmin. Check [WIMManagementCommands command group for the AdminTask object](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_atwimmgt.html?lang=en) and  [User and group management commands](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wim.doc/usermanagementcommands.html?lang=en-us&cp=SSAW57_8.5.5) . For example:

```
$AdminTask createUser {-uid dmeyers –password tempPass -confirmPassword tempPass  –cn Dan –sn Meyers –mail dmeyers@acme.com}
```

For mapping users and groups to application roles check this page: [Options for the AdminApp object](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/rxml_taskoptions.html#rxml_taskoptions__cmd58) . For example:

```
AdminApp.install('myapp.ear', '[-MapRolesToUsers [["All Role" No Yes "" ""]
 ["Every Role" Yes No "" ""] [DenyAllRole No No user1 group1]]]')
```